# Velocity dependent force with arbitrary power

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, kinematics

$\textbf{The Question:}$

Consider a particle with initial velocity $v_0 > 0$, subject only to the retarding force $F = −kv|v|^{n-1}$ with $k,n > 0$. Find $v(t)$ and $x(t)$, and investigate the behavior of $v$ and $x$ as $t → +∞$.

There will be three cases:

(a) For small $n$, the particle comes to rest after a finite time, and thus has travelled a finite distance.

(b) For intermediate $n$, the particle comes to rest only asymptotically as $t → +∞$, but the distance it travels as $t → +∞$ is finite.

(c) For large $n$, the particle comes to rest only asymptotically as $t → +∞$, and it travels an infinite distance as $t → +∞$.

Prove this scenario, find the values of $n$ that form the dividing lines between these three cases, and put the dividing-line values of n into the correct cases.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

I have no real idea about how to do this question given that we have velocity with the power $n-1$ in the question.

I can see that taking $n=1$ gives $F=-kv$ which can then be solved to give $x(t) = A + Be^{\frac{-kt}{m}}$, so if $t \rightarrow\infty$ the distance travelled is A. Using initial conditions I get that $t \rightarrow \infty, x(t)=\frac{v_{0}m}{k}$ .

It seems to me if n is very large, then the particle will slow down very quickly but when $v<1$ the force will become very small so the particle will continue travelling for a long time, and vice versa if $n$ is close to $0$.

But I don't know how to find these 'dividing lines' of $n$. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does the absolute value matter? If the initial velocity is greater than zero, doesn't that guarantee the velocity won't be negative (due to the acceleration being directly related to the velocity) and that you can remove the absolute value?

Comment: Also, it looks as though you have already found 1 of the two dividing lines, the one between small and intermediates (besides a small typo, your force for n=1 should be -kv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the general solution of the differential equation
$$m\frac{dv}{dt} = -kv|v|^{n-1}$$
Consider the substitution $u = |v|^{n-1}$ for the integration.

The solution of the above should be
$$|v(t)|=\left( \frac{kt}{m} (n-1) + v_0^{1-n} \right) ^{1 \over 1-n}$$

To find $x(t)$, consider both cases of the absolute value.

You should find out that $n=2$ is also a dividing line from $x(t)$.